# Regex: match not double quoted and with a dash in the middle

Tags: regex

From the following string

```
ar-101 "ar102" ar103 "ar-104" ar-105 "ar-106"
```

I only want to match the words that don't start or end with quotes and have a dash between two words. So from the string I want to match `ar-101` & `ar-105`

This is my regex so far, but it matches the words between quotes as well

```
\b\w+[-]\w+(?<!")\b
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/C99cFm/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it almost alright, just put your *look behind* at the start of the expression.

```regex
\b(?<!")\w+[-]\w+\b
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\b\w+[-]\w+(?<!")\b` that you tried still matches the words between quotes as there is a word boundary between double quote and a word char, and a construct like `\w+(?<!")` is always true as you match a word character and then assert directly to the left not a `"` and a word character does not match `"`

If you don't want quotes at the start and at the end, you can use negative lookarounds at both ends:

```
\b(?<!")\w+-\w+\b(?!")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/piEsme/1)

Without using lookarounds, you can also match from and to a double quote, and then use a capture group to capture what you want to keep:

```
"[^"]*"|(\w+-\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/THROLH/1)